# gcloud builds submit does not update file

Tags: docker, gcloud, gitignore, gcloudignore, gcr.io

When I run the command,
`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[MY_TAG]`
it builds the image and returns a success message.
However, when I run
`docker run gcr.io/[MY_TAG]`
I get an error on a line of a file that did exist before but I removed it and replaced it with something else.

I'd appreciate it if you give me some ideas on possible scenarios that `gcloud builds submit` may not update a file and how to force it to update the file in the image.

Note that I do not have `.gcloudignore` anywhere in my folder, the file that is not updated does not exist in `.gitignore`, and I'm not able to use `--no-cache` because it says:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) Invalid value for [no-cache]: Cannot specify --no-cache if builds/use_kaniko property is False
```

I checked the last log file generated in `gcloud\logs\` and the file that I need to update is indicated as "Added"!

Answer (score 3):

It may be that you're depending on the `latest` tag to disambiguate image versions but this does not work as expected.

When you `docker run ... ${IMAGE}:latest` on your host, if the tag exists locally, whatever image has the tag, will be run. It is possible that the GCR `:latest` is being updated but you're not using that when you run what your host has as `:latest`.

Tags are a flawed  mechanism for identifying container images. Tags are commonly used to denote versions|releases but they are, in fact, arbitrary labels and afford little by way of any guarantee.

You're much better off using digests as these are unique (for unique images)

```sh
gcloud builds submit \
--tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test \
--project=${PROJECT}
...
latest: digest: 
sha256:e5773d45cc5dce21d78f276f87928ab47373b65ef10786722a38b22918e69d7e size: 524
DONE

gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
e5773d45cc5d  latest  2020-02-06T17:21:27
```

If we submit the build again, the `:latest` tag will jump to the new image:

```
gcloud builds submit \
--tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test \
--project=${PROJECT}
...
latest: digest: 
sha256:ab9fc60674a0e854e553baa06666c898426baec9d8d2ead0ff8513dbab960d2c size: 524
DONE

gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
ab9fc60674a0  latest  2020-02-06T17:23:48
e5773d45cc5d          2020-02-06T17:21:27
```

You may run a container from a specific image digest this way:

```
docker run \
--rm --interactive --tty \
gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test@sha256:e5773d45cc5dce21d78f276f87928ab47373b65ef10786722a38b22918e69d7e

docker run \
--rm --interactive --tty \
gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test@sha256:ab9fc60674a0e854e553baa06666c898426baec9d8d2ead0ff8513dbab960d2c
```

An alternative approach that depends upon you using distinct tags (and is not as good as using virtually-guaranteed-to-be-distinct digests) is:

```sh
gcloud builds submit --tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test:v3 --project=${PROJECT}
gcloud builds submit --tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test:v4 --project=${PROJECT}

gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
5946f2e093af  v4      2020-02-06T17:28:36
f03c9609c101  v3      2020-02-06T17:28:17
ab9fc60674a0  latest  2020-02-06T17:23:48
e5773d45cc5d          2020-02-06T17:21:27
```

**NB** Because we've been judicious, we have distinct digests for distinct tags. However, if we were to inadvertently reuse `v4`, different copies of the image would once again be inconsistent:

Let's pull the image that currently (!) corresponds to `:v4`:

```
docker pull gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test:v4
Digest: sha256:5946f2e093afbe203691cdc8a3e592db7b3e1d010619c4c97c3084de299f4d06

docker image ls
REPOSITORY                               TAG      IMAGE ID
gcr.io/dazwilkin-200206-60102073/test    v4       a1bb9204b417
```

Build the image reusing (!) `:v4` and pull it again:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test:v4 --project=${PROJECT}
Digest:
sha256:e128e4fe3d61fee0c995e9ac2cd1f05635fbdc017f32eb3116fdb593826674cc

gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
e128e4fe3d61  v4      2020-02-06T17:36:59
5946f2e093af          2020-02-06T17:28:36
f03c9609c101  v3      2020-02-06T17:28:17
ab9fc60674a0  latest  2020-02-06T17:23:48
e5773d45cc5d          2020-02-06T17:21:27
```

**NB** How the `:v4` tag has jumped to the new digest (`e128...`).

But, the image with `:v4` tag locally is the old image (`5946...`).

It's only when we (remember to) pull the `:v4` tagged image again that we'll pull what's currently tagged as `:v4` on GCR.

```
docker pull gcr.io/${PROJECT}/test:v4
Digest: sha256:e128e4fe3d61fee0c995e9ac2cd1f05635fbdc017f32eb3116fdb593826674cc
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/dazwilkin-200206-60102073/test:v4

docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                TAG      IMAGE ID
gcr.io/dazwilkin-200206-60102073/test     v4       6a916f95586a
```

**NB** Same tag (`:v4`) but the digests (a hash) are unique to image builds.